# Multiple forms on one page bugging textarea default value

Tags: html, forms

An image can best show the problem:
[image]

Of course I dont want my textarea to have a bunch of html tags as a default value, thats why I set the defaultvalue to 'Hi', which it aparently isnt showing right now, but which it should.

I already tried a few things to find/solve the problem. What I found out is that if I remove the other form on the page (a login form not visible on the image) this form works and properly shows 'Hi' as a value. So the problem seems to be that there are multiple forms on this page. Problem has only shown with the use of text-area's, input fields, on this page or any other, work fine. I also tried moving the textarea outside of the form tags, that does remove the html tags, but the 'hi' still isnt visible (plus I want the textarea inside my form, as it should be part of it).

Edit, after a few struggles finally managed to post the code as code instead of a document. Code for the first, properly working, form:

```
<div id="userbox">
<form id="form1" action="auth/login" method="post">
    <div id="username-container">
        <input class="transparent-input" name="username" type="text" value="Gebruikersnaam">
    </div>
    <div id="password-container">
        <input class="transparent-input" name="password"   type="password" value="Wachtwoord">
    </div>
    <div id="lostpass-container">
        <a href="">wachtwoord<br />vergeten?</a>
    </div>
    <div id="login-container">
        <input class="transparent-input"  type="submit" value="Aanmelden">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Code for the second, faulty, form:

```
<div id="content">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" value="Pietje Puk" /><br />
        <input type="email" value="mijn@email.nl" /><br />
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50">Hi</textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

edit: I did do a markup validation, nothing there that solved the problem

Comment: Post your code, please. If you're having trouble, ask for help.

Comment: I did post my code (as I wrote), but somehow it bugged out and partially disappeared. Thats why I now posted it as an image, hope that is alright :)

Comment: Did you try to validate the resulting code to see where the markup is broken?

Comment: No, it's not all right. It makes testing it rather difficult. It also makes this question worthless to the SO community after you delete the file from your Google Drive.

Comment: Wow, what did I do wrong to deserve the tough love treatment? Its kinda impossible to post the code because somehow it actually executes the code and shows the result of the html rather than the actual code. I have now uploaded it as a google document where people can copy the code if they want to execute it. (edit: ofc I promise to not delete the document, I wouldnt have anyway)

Comment: Please have a look at this link for adding code to your post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Thanks for the link Mark, I fiddled a bit with the suggestions there, and finally managed to solve the 'not being able to post the code'-problem by fiddling with the amount of tabs in front of the code. Thanks :) I do want to note that the downvotes, and isherwoods responses havent really made me feel welcome here. I only once before posted a question on one of the stackexchange sites so Im kinda new to this thing, also I did put a lot of effort in trying to solve the problem before I finally posted it as an image. Nothing to crucify me over.

Comment: I'm not really sure what problem you're having. Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/q5p4F/1/

Comment: Yeah, I just solved the problem. It turned out to be a markup problem after all. Aparently a closing tag of a div was positioned wrong somewhere else on the page, that the markup validator didnt pick up. I tried to post an answer but its too early, and I cant edit my post now because an admin kindly posted the image in there xD

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a markup problem after all. After trying some more I did find that moving a div closing tag to a different location in the document did solve the problem. Before I had opened a div before both forms and closed it in between them, closing it after both of them instead solved the problem.

Tnx Lars Beck for pointing me in the right direction :)